# Are the relations of being homeomorphic or being homotopy equivalent on the compact polyhedra definable in the structure of the natural numbers?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lo.logic, metamathematics

Let $ K(\mathbb{N}) $ denote the set of all finite simplicial complexes with vertices in $\mathbb{N}$.
Let $ f\colon \mathbb{N} \to K(\mathbb{N}) $ be a computable bijection.
Let $ R $ = { $ (m, n) $ | $ m, n $ are natural numbers and the polyhedra $ |f(m)| $ and $ |f(n)| $ are homeomorphic }
and $ S $ = { $ (m, n) $ | $ m, n $ are natural numbers and the polyhedra $ |f(m)| $ and $ |f(n)| $ are homotopy equivalent }.
Are the relations $ R $ and $ S $ definable in the structure $ \mathbb{N} $?

Comment: They should be, thanks to simplicial approximation - it basically asserts that if we allow for subdivisions, then we can restrict to simplicial maps between the polytopes, which we can enumerate.

Comment: I would guess the relations are definable but not computable. I think this contains the group presentation isomorphism problem, right?

Comment: Among the spaces $K(G, 1)$, exactly those spaces for which $G$ is a finitely presented torsion-free group are realized as finite complexes. Is the problem of isomophorism also unsolvable for presentations of such groups? Or do you mean some other inclusion between these problems?

Comment: @ZhenLin The relation _R_ is not computable because the problem of determining whether the topological realization of some finite simplicial complex is homeomorphic to the _d-sphere_ $ S^d $ is undecidable for each $ d ≥ 5 $ (proved by P.S. Novikov). But whether _S_ is also an uncomputable relation, I don't know.